# What is the correct syntax to supply a class to Mockito.any() so that the verify() call is unambiguous?

Tags: java, generics, mockito, ambiguous-call

I'm using `Mockito.spy(...)` on a non-Mock object to verify that one of its methods is never called. However, there's an ambiguity because I'm just using `any(), any()`, and there are two overloads with two parameters:

[image]

I'm a bit new to Java and can't figure out the right way to express what Mockito wants from me. I think I don't have a good handle on reflective concepts in Java, *e.g.* difference between `Class`, `Function`, lambdas, etc.

Here's an example of an *actual* (non-Mockito) use of that method:

```
        return jdbiExecutor.execute(Foo.class,
            foo -> {
              // Some code.
              return Bar.newBuilder().build();
            });
```

So, what I'm trying to verify is the first overload that takes a `Function<D, T>` for its second parameter. Some things I've tried but don't work:

```
// Is specifying just one of the parameters enough?
verifyZeroInteractions(executor.execute(any(Foo, any()));

// Maybe I need to supply the `.class()`?
verifyZeroInteractions(executor.execute(any(Foo.class, any()));

// Or literally, `Class<Foo>`?
verifyZeroInteractions(executor.execute(any(Class<Foo>), any()));

// Or what, do I _have_ to specify both parameters to some degree?
```

How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should give the explicit type to compiler

```
executor.execute(any(), Matchers.<Function<?, ?>> any()); // here ? can be your explicit type
```